# prefersStatusBarHidden and Black bar in window after backgrounding an iPhone only app on iPad iOS 8

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, statusbar, appearance

When running my iPhone only app on an iPad with iOS 8 I've had a black bar appearing in my application's window. I can reproduce it reliably by backgrounding the app in landscape, then re-opening in portrait. Everything is fine on an iPhone.

To try and eliminate some extra factors I've replaced the initial viewcontroller in my storyboard with an xcode default new viewcontroller file. The black bar persists on my otherwise blank white window.

When the app is running "normally", the window looks to be padded with a grey area at the top. The black bar appears to "fall out" of this grey area and end up in the middle of my window.

I've tried setting "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO. Then, adding the following to prefersStatusBarHidden gets rid of the annoying bar, but then my navbar gets cropped from the top!

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
 UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]    statusBarOrientation];
  switch(orientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
      return NO;

    default:
      return YES;
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if any of you know the cause/ cure for this?

See below for screen shots...

The Black bar!

[image: Black bar]

App running normally, note padded grey area at the top of the screen.

[image: App running "normally"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issues by...

1. Setting "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO.
2. Testing for iOS version and setting my NavBar background image accordingly...

   ```
   NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
   bool isAtLeastiOS_8 = [version floatValue] >= 8.0;

   if(isAtLeastiOS_8) {
     UIImage *bgImagePortrait = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarPortrait.png"];    
     [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:bgImagePortrait forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   } else {
     UIImage *bgImagePortrait = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarPortrait.png"];
     UIImage *bgImageLandscape = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarLandscape.png"];

     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:bgImagePortrait
                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:bgImageLandscape
                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
   }
   ```
3. Accepting the loss of the status bar in landscape mode on iOS 8

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: iPhone apps showing a black bar in landscape on retina iPads. It only happens if I use

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden { return NO; }
```

to override iOS 8's default behavior of hiding the status bar in landscape.

The black bar on mine is always 300x20 points in size (e.g., the size of the status bar in portrait, minus a 20-pixel-wide chunk) and has an alpha of around 0.9. It appears to be the mask that the iPhone emulation mode on the iPad uses for the iPhone app's portrait-mode status bar area (!); if I don't override iOS 8's preference, so there is no status bar in landscape, it works fine. It looks to me like a bug in iOS 8's iPhone emulation on iPad... just one more in a long line of iOS 8 bugs... :-(

My "fix" is to turn off the status bar only on iPads running iOS 8+:

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] hasPrefix:@"iPad"] &&
        (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)) {
        return YES;
    }
    else return NO;
}
```